# What is the purpose of the comment notification bar?

Tags: discussion, comments, notification-bar

When I logged in today, I saw an orange notification bar informing me that I had 1 new comment.

What is the purpose of this notification when I already have the inbox in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Comment: That notification bar existed long before the MultiCollider did.

Comment: @PopularDemand, I know, but when I've seen the orange bar it has been for things like badge notifications. Why is it notifying me of comments when that is now the MultiCollider's job? Basically I'm wondering why I'm being notified twice of a comment.

Comment: Yeah, that was just an FYI for newer users. If I knew the why, I would have posted an actual answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

That notification bar serves to annoy users.  Oh, and to vex them.  Yes.  Vexation.  It fully vexes me every time I see it.  Every time I click on a link in that bar, which fails to close it.  Every.  Time.

Comment: Just wanted to say that it's doing a fine job.

Comment: @eykanal: Not really.  When you click a link on the StackExchange MultiCollider SuperDerpdown it should *dismiss that particular StackExchange MultiCollider SuperDerpdown*.  You shouldn't have to click the bloody X on the bar.  And it shouldn't be duplicated in the inbox (I don't think it is anymore).

Comment: I apologize for my poor attempt at humor. The comment was intended to be tongue-in-cheek, "it's doing a fine job annoying users".

Comment: @eykanal: I herped when I should have derped.