# Is the extra notification necessary?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the comment notification bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114200/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-comment-notification-bar)

When someone responds to a comment we get a notification in our global inbox and at the same time there's a notification in the response tab in the profile page.
Shouldn't both the notifications expire if one of them is checked?
Gets a little annoying at times.

Comment: The official name is [MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/172936) ;)